# Laravel 4: Sorting comments by how many 'Likes' they have

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

I have two tables: Comments and CommentRatings

What I'm trying to do is get Comments but order them by how many likes they have in the CommentRatings table but I just can't figure it out and figured I would have more luck asking here

So here's my Comments Table:
[image]

Here's the CommentRatings Table:

[image]

Ideally I need to be able to sort it by how many likes there are from this but literally have no clue

```
         $comments = Comment::where('url', Request::url())
            ->take($limit)
             ->get()
```

Comment: Maybe, if you create a database view you can do it easier. Then, you can map your view to a Laravel model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't actively develop with Laravel 4, but I took a stab at it. Hopefully it will work in 4. Tested in Laravel 5, but let me know if this throws any error.

```
 $comments = Comment::where('url', Request::url())
        ->select(DB::raw('comments.*, count(*) as `comments_count`'))
        ->join('comment_ratings', 'comments.id', '=', 'comment_ratings.comment_id')
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->orderBy('comments_count', 'desc')
        ->take($limit);
```